# Class App\Http\Controllers\cartlistController does not exist,why?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just copy the controller files from another laravel projecet to this project now I am doing,and then it shows like the title.what's wrong with it?

```
in Route.php line 280 at ReflectionMethod->__construct() in
Route.php line 0 at
Route->signatureParameters('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model') in
Router.php line 859 at
Router->substituteImplicitBindings(object(Route)) in Router.php line
844 at Router->substituteBindings(object(Route)) in Router.php line
827 at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691 at
Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675 at
Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246 at
Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) at
call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
line 52 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44 at
CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode),
'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
line 136 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
line 32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
line 103 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php
line 99 at Kernel->handle(

object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: What version of Laravel were you / are you using?

Comment: the version is 5.2 @Brayniverse

Comment: Is the controller class supposed to be lowercase? You've got `cartlistController` but convention is usually `CartlistController`. Could it be a typographical error?

Comment: not a typographical error,because the other controller work well

Comment: thanks..it's a typographical error,i forgot a word

Comment: Glad you figured it out